# Why does not gdistance::shortestPath produce a straight line?

Tags: r

I want to calculate a least-cost path using `gdistance::shortestPath`. I have a raster file showing the cost of passing each cell, but before using it, I try to mimic the example 1 in the [pdf manual](https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-02-04/web/packages/gdistance/vignettes/gdistance1.pdf) to see how the package works as below when we assume constant cost to travel across cells.

```
library(gdistance)


raster <- raster(ymn = 35.6, ymx = 35.76, xmx = 139.9, xmn = 139.6, res = 0.001)

raster[] <- 1

speed <- function(x){1/(x[2]+x[1])}

# 8 is possible connections
trraster <- transition(raster, transitionFunction=speed, 8)
trraster <- geoCorrection(trraster, scl=FALSE)
plot(raster(trraster))

adj <- adjacent(raster, cells=1:ncell(raster), pairs=TRUE, directions=8)
speed <- trraster
# this is the cost function 
speed[adj] <-trraster[adj]


x <- geoCorrection(speed, scl=FALSE)


origin <- c(139.7761,35.7136)
goal <- c(139.7582,35.66639)
path <- shortestPath(x, origin, goal, output="SpatialLines")
plot(raster(speed))
lines(path)
```

Because this assume constant costs to travel (See `raster[] <- 1` and `speed <- function(x){1/(x[2]+x[1])}`), the result must be a straight line, but the result is different as below.

[image]

It does not seem to allow us travel cells diagonally. What is wrong with the code? I set direction as 8, so we should be able to travel cells diagonally. I am using `gdistance 1.3-6` and `R 4.0.5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing `trraster <- geoCorrection(trraster, scl=FALSE)`. In the original pdf manual, they apply `geoCorrection` twice to adjust the distance between cells when they calculate the slope (height difference / distance) and conductance (speed / distance). However, in my case, speed is constant, so we only need to apply it once in `x <- geoCorrection(speed, scl=FALSE)`.